# I did the Expression Engine upgrade to 2.61 and now when I add a PAGE it won't let me set the status

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades

I did the Expression Engine upgrade to 2.61 and now when I add a PAGE it won't let me set the status it just is blank so I can not set it to open. if I add or update it sets to blank...
what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a status group assigned to that channel.